# Error running JPA2.0 on IBM Websphere 7 (WAS 7) environement

Tags: jpa

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.3.1: Value '2.0' of attribute 'version' of element 'persistence' is not valid with respect to the corresponding attribute use. Attribute 'version' has a fixed value of '1.0'.

    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:848)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:773)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl$1.run(AdminServiceImpl.java:1320)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:118)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl.invoke(AdminServiceImpl.java:1213)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.application.AppManagementImpl._startApplication(AppManagementImpl.java:1299)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.application.AppManagementImpl.startApplication(AppManagementImpl.java:1195)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.application.AppManagementImpl.startApplication(AppManagementImpl.java:1155)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:48)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:600)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:37)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor11.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:600)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:244)
    at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invokeMethod(RequiredModelMBean.java:1086)
    at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invoke(RequiredModelMBean.java:967)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:848)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:773)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl$1.run(AdminServiceImpl.java:1320)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:118)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl.invoke(AdminServiceImpl.java:1213)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.remote.AdminServiceForwarder.invoke(AdminServiceForwarder.java:334)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1438)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$200(RMIConnectionImpl.java:84)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1276)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1355)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:800)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi._RMIConnectionImpl_Tie.invoke(_RMIConnectionImpl_Tie.java:750)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi._RMIConnectionImpl_Tie._invoke(_RMIConnectionImpl_Tie.java:158)
    at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ServerDelegate.dispatchInvokeHandler(ServerDelegate.java:622)
    at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ServerDelegate.dispatch(ServerDelegate.java:475)
    at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.ORB.process(ORB.java:513)
    at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ORB.process(ORB.java:1574)
    at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.Connection.respondTo(Connection.java:2841)
    at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.Connection.doWork(Connection.java:2714)
    at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.WorkUnitImpl.doWork(WorkUnitImpl.java:63)
    at com.ibm.ejs.oa.pool.PooledThread.run(ThreadPool.java:118)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1550)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.3.1: Value '2.0' of attribute 'version' of element 'persistence' is not valid with respect to the corresponding attribute use. Attribute 'version' has a fixed value of '1.0'.
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator$XSIErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.reportSchemaError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.processOneAttribute(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.processAttributes(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.validation.ValidatorHandlerImpl.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.ValidatingUnmarshaller.startElement(ValidatingUnmarshaller.java:85)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.SAXConnector.startElement(SAXConnector.java:113)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDispatcher.scanRootElementHook(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:202)
    ... 78 more
```

Comment: What's your question? Please provide more details. Also, I suggest you read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

solved above problem by adding following property in IBM Websphere WAS 7 admin console:
Application servers > server1 > Java and Process Management > Process definition > Java Virtual Machine > New

Name: com.ibm.websphere.persistence.ApplicationsExcludedFromJpaProcessing 
Value: *